# Почему съехала вёрстка?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет. Работаю над сайтом, всё было ок. В процессе заметил, что на одной из страниц формы стали маленькими. Раньше были на всю ширину блока.

Сколько не копался в дебагере, тестил по разному - всё тщетно. Не вытягивается. Пните пожалуйста в нужную сторону, уже несколько дней залип.

Ссылочка на пациента [тут](http://cg54725.tmweb.ru/checkout/)
Формы на странице оформления заказа. Чтобы увидеть её перейдя по ссылке, нужно http://cg54725.tmweb.ru/shop/bukety/buket-16/ добавить в корзину

Comment: а на какой странице формы-то?

Comment: @humster_spb оставил ссылку же

Comment: она ведёт просто в корзину - никаких форм там не вижу

Comment: @humster_spb а , это потому что корзина пуста. Формы находятся на странице оформления заказа (checkout)

Comment: так там нет ни одного товара, чтоб его можно было добавить в корзину :)))

Comment: @humster_spb http://cg54725.tmweb.ru/shop/bukety/buket-16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у родительского блока инпута нету класса в css. и задайте ему width: 100%; и все будет ок.

```css
class="woocommerce-input-wrapper" 

.woocommerce-input-wrapper{
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: вы лучший!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: скрин]

О каком блоке идет речь?

Если о сумме заказа там width: 48%; задан.
Если о блоке товаров он упирается в container max-width: 1140px;

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, речь идёт о странице оформления заказа checkout. Она следующая